# Flex / AS3 : Red Eye reduction

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I was looking a component to reduce red eye effect on taken photos. Ive found an image Processing library, but it does not work well at all. I was thinking on brush an image, manually, and only paint if the base pixel color its red or near in RGB.

Have no time now to explain all the process, but i need help to get this idea, or to get a working comp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wishing to manipulate the pixels of an image/component then pixelbender would be a pretty good way to go.

Have a look at http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=26 for downloadable examples.

These can be run using the toolkit found at http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbender/

Video tutorials on pixel bender can be found at http://www.gotoandlearn.com/

With this you could change just the required pixel colours to anything and it works with everything in flash (images, canvas, button's etc)